# ifstream doesn't get data from file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I've started learning C++, and got a bit of a problem with homework.

The issue is: `ifstream` opens a file, but for some reason can't extract any data from it. The `.txt` file is in the same directory as `main.cpp`.

I'm 100% sure the compiler opens the file, because I don't receive an error.

As you can see below, I've made 2 structs, `Person` (which contains 2 strings: `Surname`, `Firstname`, and optional `Middlename`), and `PhoneNumber` (which contains: `int Countrynumber`, `int CityNumber`, `string phonenumber`, and optional additional number).

The whole code is pretty massive, so I don't think I should paste it here.

```cpp
class PhoneBook
{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<Person, PhoneNumber>> contact;

public:

    PhoneBook(std::ifstream& ifs)
    {
        std::string sN, fN;
        std::optional<std::string> mN;
        int countryNum, cityNum;
        std::string phoneNum;
        std::optional<int> addNum;
        std::optional<std::string> aN;

        if (ifs.is_open())  
        {
            while (ifs >> sN >> fN >> mN.emplace() >> countryNum >> cityNum >> phoneNum >> addNum.emplace())
            {
                if (mN.has_value())
                    if (mN.value() == "-")
                    {
                        mN = std::nullopt;
                    }
                Person p(sN, fN, mN);
                if (addNum.has_value())
                {
                    if (aN.value() == "-")
                    {
                        addNum = std::nullopt;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        addNum.emplace() = std::stoi(aN.value());
                    }
                }
                PhoneNumber ph1(countryNum, cityNum, phoneNum, addNum);
    
                contact.push_back(std::make_pair(p, ph1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error, couldn't open the file." << std::endl;
        }
    
        ifs.close();
    }
};
```

And here is the `main()` function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("PhoneBook.txt"); 
    PhoneBook book(file);
    std::cout << book;
}
```

By the way, I've overloaded `operator<<` for the class `PhoneBook` and it works, so that's not the issue.

And here is the `.txt` file:

```
Ilin Petr Artemovich 7 17 4559767 -
Zaitsev Zakhar Artemovich 125 44 4164751 -
Dubinin Aleksei Mikhailovich 7 473 7449054 -
Solovev Artur Mikhailovich 4 940 2556793 -
Gerasimov Miroslav Stanislavovich 7 367 7508887 -
Makeev Marat - 77 4521 8880876 999
Solovev Ivan Vladimirovich 7 273 5699819 5543
Egorov Savelii Stanislavovich 77 4521 8880876 99
Sokolov Arsenii - 93 163 1992257 16
Davydov Filipp Grigorevich 7 247 1377660 -
Morozov Vladimir Mikhailovich 37 2290 5613649 -
Orekhov Matvei Petrovich 81 8281 7420182 2
Titova Natalia - 93 163 1992257 9
Markelov Dmitrii Vadimovich 19 7576 5734416 2
Kozlovskii Artem Daniilovich 81 8281 7420182 1
Kuznetsov Kirill Kirillovich 7 017 8346563 -
Mironova Margarita Aleksandrovna 7 273 5699819 5542
Kotov Vasilii Eliseevich 7 367 7508888 -
Ivanov Daniil Maksimovich 7 366 7508887 -
Aleksandrov Georgii - 493 7637 6114861 -
```

Comment: I'd guess it's more about trying to read `-` into `int` variable. That will stop the loop immediately.

Comment: Since the file is line-oriented, I would suggest reading the file using a `std::getline()` loop, using a secondary `std::istringstream` to parse each line.